# Repast - locate and track a specific agent using agent monitor

Tags: repast-simphony

I have 500000+ agents which are added in the context but not in the display. Is there an easy way for me to locate a specific agent (without displaying it) and track its property change over time using the agent monitor like below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The probe panel is only available through displays so you would need to be able to click on a specific agent.  You might be able to use the agent table via the table icon in the toolbar which will provide a snapshot of all of the agents and their properties at a specific time.

If you know the ID of the agent you want to probe before the model is run, you could selectively log data from a single agent, or you could have a display with just a single agent by specifying in the style class that the returned shape is null for all agents except the agents you would like to see.  That way it would at least be possible to show a few agents in the display and probe them.

Comment: thanks. Is it possible to perform some manual query at a specific tick? like in Netlogo, we can run the model for 50 ticks, then pause and write a query to check, for instance, how many agents are in a specific list or the properties of a specific group of agents, without writing the print function in the code. this is very efficient for debugging.

Comment: Have you looked at the built in agent table functionality? There's a brief description in section 1.3 of the Repast Java Getting Started Guide: https://repast.github.io/docs/RepastJavaGettingStarted.pdf